# replace placeholder with value from hash table

Tags: c#, regex

I have text with placeholder as below

> "My name is |@NAME@| My Age is |@AGE@|"

and I have < string, string>  Dictionary that contain each placeholder and its value based on the that dictionary

so I need to replace each placeholder with its value

I tried this but it's not working

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"\|@([^\@|]+)\}", RegexOptions.Compiled);

 string newStr  = regex.Replace(
     originalString, 
     delegate(Match match) 
     {
         return placeholder[match.Groups[1].Value];
     });
```

Comment: Why did you use a curly brace? You need `\|` - `@"\|@([^@|]+)@\|"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your regex, `\}` matches a `}` that is missing in your input.

You need to use

```
@"\|@(.+?)@\|"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%7c%40%28.%2b%3f%29%40%5c%7c&i=My+name+is+%7c%40NAME%40%7c+My+Age+is+%7c%40AGE%40%7c)

**Details**:

- `\|@` - a `|@` char sequence
- `(.+?)` - capturing group #1 matching any one or more chars other than a newline
- `@\|` - a `@|` char sequence.

In the code, you may use

```
string newStr  = Regex.Replace(
            originalString, 
            @"\|@(.+?)@\|",
            match => placeholder.ContainsKey(match.Groups[1].Value) ?
                     placeholder[match.Groups[1].Value] : match.Value
          );
```

Comment: The capturing group `(([^@]+)` would do the same, but I'd rather use the more tolerant `((?:(?!@\|).)+)` (which would also work with placeholders that have a `@` or `|` in them as long as it is not the end sequence).

Comment: @Lucero: Well, then I'd rather suggest a classical `.*?`, the tempered greedy token makes no sense here since there is no 3rd string to exclude between 2 delimiters. See [When to Use this Technique](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

Comment: I prefer it to be explicit ;) but of course the lazy pattern is fine as well.

Comment: I got exception  {"The given key was not present in the dictionary."}

Comment: @user7157121: I adjusted the MatchEvaluator part so that it will return the match value if the `placeholder`  dictionary has no key with the value inside Group 1.